# Why using symfony route annotations doesn't work?

Tags: php, symfony, annotations

I'm trying to use this route

```
/** 
*@Route("/random/string/{length<\d>?5}", name="string")
*/
public function getString(Request $request, $length)
    {
        $string = "";
        for ($i=0; $i < $lenght; $i++) { 
            $string .= chr(random_int(65, 90)); // adds a random char to the string
        }
        str_shuffle( $string );
        return new Response("Random string : $string");
    }
```

I've imported this

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
```

and i've ran

```
composer require annotations
```

when i run debug router or try to follow this route i get the error message :

> [critical] Uncaught Error: syntax error, unexpected identifier " ",
> expecting "function" or "const"

Comment: The error suggests you have a _syntax_ error. The easiest fix for that is to use a good IDE. I recommend [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/). A good IDE will help you see syntax errors and 'fix' problems for you before they happen. Since you are obviously copy/pasting, I can't be sure of your specific issue. I suspect you are missing a space in the docblock between the * and the @.

Comment: The line number of an error log is quite usefull also

Comment: Are you using the actual Symfony framework or doing something with just the router?  The framework should just work out of the box.  If it's your own project then [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59637483/can-i-use-symfonys-route-annotation-in-non-symfony-project/59648421#59648421).  There are quite a few things to setup.

Comment: I'm using Vs Code, these : https://imgur.com/a/nlc34ZK are the errors that the IDE provides, it did point to the fact that it was a syntax error but it wasn't really helpfull in fiding wich. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right format. If still it is not working then I think the syntax error is in import statement in your class file.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/random/string/{length<\d+>?5}", name="string")
 */
public function getString(int $length, Request $request)
{
    $string = "";
    for ($i=0; $i < $lenght; $i++) {
        $string .= chr(random_int(65, 90)); // adds a random char to the string
    }
    str_shuffle( $string );
    return new Response("Random string :". $string);
}
```

Comment: I copy pasted your annotation and it fixed the issue, i think the 2nd and 3rd lines of * where not indented correctly by one space.

Didn't realised it was so sensitive to small differences in syntax.

Thanks.